# How region selection affects NextJS application on Azure Static Web App

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-static-web-app

Recently I've tested NextJS SSR on Azure Static Web App. It looks promising.

The only thing that I can't find in the docs is how Region selection affects performance in this case.
[image]

I assume NextJS SSR is converted to Azure Function, I can even see a clue in the portal:

[image]

Where exactly is this function running? In the datacenter I choose when creating Static Web App or on edge servers? Unfortunately, official documentation is very laconic when it comes to such internals.

Answer (score 0):

> The only thing that I can't find in the docs is how Region selection affects performance in this case.

AFAIK, Static Web Apps are distributed globally. It can't impact performance. As per the [Ms-Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/faq#how-do-i-ensure-my-app-is-deployed-to-a-specific-azure-region-) Azure static Apps are globally distributed. You can select the region where the **Managed Azure Function App** is deployed while deploying.

> If you need your Functions app in a region that doesn't support managed functions, you can use the [Bring your own Functions app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/functions-bring-your-own) feature with a Functions app you deploy separately.

While deploying your app into azure you can be able to select the region to deploy.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but you gave absolutely no answer to my question. Those facts are known from docs, but how it affects NextJS SSR application is somehow blurry for me. If my conclusions are correct, all server-side NextJS components are silently converted to Azure Function so in this case almost everything apart from static assets is being served from just one location. That is what I want to clarify